# Войти в Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql

При входе в Microsoft SQL Management Studio требует ввести server name. Что туда вводить? Пробовал local, но соединения не происходит. Ошибка: не найден сетевой путь.

Comment: Если полная версия попробуйте (local) или 127.0.0.1.

Если Express - (local)\SQLEXPRESS или 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Там есть поиск серверов, студия способна распознать в большинстве случаев sql сервера в сети и на локальном компьютере.

Comment: Версия полная (Microsoft SQL Server 2014), оба варианта не работают. Появляется все та же ошибка. Точнее, 2: (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Не удалось открыть подключение к SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: Что то не могу найти "поиск серверов"

Comment: возможно у вас также не запущена служба sql-сервера

Comment: Помимо службы, включите еще TCP/IP в сетевых настройках.

Comment: @progerstudent, служба сервера sql точно запущена?

У меня под рукой 2008 студия. В окне соединения с сервером кнопка раскрывает список имён сервера, выбираем обзор, в открывшемся окне вторая закладка "сетевые сервера", там должен появится список найденных, через несколько секунд.

Ну и на всякий случай, в окне авторизации должен быть выбран пункт "компонент database engine" в поле типа сервера.

Comment: у меня в "службах" вообще нет MSSQLSERVER или чего-либо подобного.

Comment: Можно открыть Configuration Manager и посмотреть, какие установлены сервера и как они работают(если они вообще есть). В "службах SQL Server" сервера называются как SQL Server(<имя_сервера>) и статус, запущены ли они. В сетевых конфигурациях прописаны к каждому серверу протоколы, по которым с ними можно взаимодействовать. При включение TCP/IP надо еще открывать IP-адреса там же. Можно еще проверить брандмаузер и открыть доступ к С:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.<имя_сервера>\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe

Answer (score 2):

Нажмите **Win+R**, в появившемся окошке вбейте **services.msc**, нажмите ОК. В появившемся списке служб найдите что-то вроде **SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)** или **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)**, посмотрите статус службы. Если служба остановлена, то запустите её. Также взгляните на утилиту Sql Server Configuration Manager (его можно найти в меню "Пуск") - в ней отображаются необходимые службы

Comment: в списке служб нашел только "SQL Server, службы синхронизации контроль версий", и эта служба работает (состояние: выполняется). А в утилите Sql Server Configuration Manager во вкладке "SQL server services" вообще пусто (нет элементов для отображения...)

Comment: значит у вас установлена только Management Studio без собственно sql-сервера

Comment: То есть скачать Microsoft SQL Server 2014 недостаточно? Нужно еще что то докачивать?

Comment: вообще достаточно. Но не факт, что вы скачали и/или установили то, что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Имя компьютера вбивайте. Если комп называется, к примеру, 1C-COMP, то так и вбивайте в это поле.

Comment: Нет, по имени тоже не заходит

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы скачали только managment, надо еще саму sql скачать [тут можете скачать sql2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42299)